# delete a parent node via javascript ( a new approach)

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine had a javascript test, and there was this question that doesn't leave me alone. I thought you guys might hav an answer.
Consider this simple html

```
<div>
  <img src='whatever'>
  <button>x</button>
<div>
<div>
  <img src='whatever2'>
  <button>x</button>
<div>
```

we want the click on button fires a function **which takes no parameter** to delete the parent node of the clicked button.

```
function deleteParent(){

}
```

can you suggest an idea? remember the key is that the function wont get a parameter

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: This is trivial, the answer is to use `addEventListener`, that way it's just `this.parentNode.remove()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/td0hL2jn/

Comment: Or even with inline handlers -> https://jsfiddle.net/td0hL2jn/1/

Comment: Thanks guys for fast reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you would have to first add a listener to your buttons to listen to the click event, when this event is executed remove the parent node with  `this.parentNode.remove();`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(elem){
 elem.addEventListener("click",function(){
   this.parentNode.remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <img src=''>
  <button>x</button>
</div>
<div>
  <img src=''>
  <button>x</button>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps worth supplying a non ECMA 5 version (ie. no arrow function/foreach) for compatibility with older browsers?